# How to apply triangle shape to an image?

Tags: css, css-shapes

have tried the below code but my image didnt change to the triangle shape. Help me with some solutions for my problem

```
.triangle {
 border-left: 50px solid transparent;
 border-right: 50px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: you add only transparent border.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/   

If you're trying to clip an `img` into a triangle, this won't work

Comment: use absolute property or set width & height

Comment: more details please of what image you need to in that triangle :p

Answer (score 3):

If you play about with the borders, and you have a solid color for a background, you could use something like:

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-bottom: 300px solid transparent;
  border-left: 150px solid white;
  border-right: 150px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Which is using a pseudo element to 'clip' the triangle shape

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.triangle {      
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-bottom: 116px solid blue;
  border-left: 116px solid transparent;
  border-right: 116px solid transparent;
}
```

Fiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/Khumesh/kpm1feLo/

Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Khumesh/zbh3ewLd/

Comment: I dont want the blue color instead  want change to my image to a triangle shape.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to clip an image into the shape of a rectangle, use `clip-path`.

Here's a nice helper: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/